# How to retrieve the metadata for Apex class security.?

Tags: apex

I want to retrieve the apex class security using ANT/ workbench.

What I need to define in the package.xml to retrieve the apex class security.

[image: Apex security]

[image: Profiles]

---

please let me how I can retrieve this metadata.

Comment: I have gone through Metadata api SFDC documentation       
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_classes.htm                                                                                             but couldn't find the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apex class security is defined as a part of the profile or permission set XML file and would be something like as shown below (after retrieval):

```
...
<classAccesses>
      <apexClass>CustomApexClassName</apexClass>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
...
```

So, all you need to do is to specify the required apex class names and the profile names in your `package.xml` file. Something like the snippet shown below:

```
...
<types>
    <members>CustomApexClassName</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>MyProfileName</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
...
```

***Note that just specifying the profile alone in the `package.xml` will not work. Specify the appropriate the apex class and profile names in the `package.xml` (the snippets above show the placeholder names)***

You may refer the Metadata API developer guide [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm) & [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm). Security settings for all of the components list below are retrieved as a part of profile or permission set file.

> In API version 29.0 and later, you can retrieve and deploy access
> settings for the following managed components in profiles and
> permission sets:
>
> - Apex classes
> - Apps
> - Custom field permissions
> - Custom object permissions
> - Custom tab settings
> - External data sources
> - Record types
> - Visualforce pages

Comment: Thank you for answering and adding the documentation link.

Comment: There will be some other standard tags like `custom`, `userLicense`, `userPermissions` etc, but those can be ignored. But yes class name and profile both are mandatory. 

Also for bulk retrieval keep all class and profile nodes, or add wild character 

    `<types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClasses</name>
    </types>`